# Using a MySQL Select with a RegEx Expression embedded within a String

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using PHP to access a mysql database field that contains up to 2500 characters per record.
I want to build queries that will return only the records that include a single word, like 'taco'.

Sometimes, however, the user will need to search for a word like 'jalapeno'. Except that jalapeno may exist in the database as 'jalapeno' or as 'jalapeño'. The query should return both  instances.

As a further complication, the user may also need to search for a word like 'creme', which may appear as 'creme' or 'créme', but never as 'crémé'.

It seems like I should be able to construct something that uses a replace, and then a Regular Expression, so that the letter 'n' is always replaced with '[n|ñ]', and then search for a string with an embedded Regular Expression like this: 'jalape[n|ñ]o'. Except that does not work. MySQL treats the RegEx syntax as literals.

None of the following return the results that I am looking for:

```
SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE record like '%jalapeno%';

SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE record REGEXP 'jalapeno';

SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE record REGEXP 'jalape[n|ñ]o';

SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(record, 'jalape[n|ñ]o', 'im');
```

Additionally, I can use PHP to do a replacement of the potential characters, but I end up with stuff like this:
SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE (record like '%creme%' || record like '%crémé%');

I would be Ok with a search like this, but it seems overly complicated to construct programmatically:

```
SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE (record like '%creme%' || record like '%crémé%' || record like '%cremé%' || record like '%cremé%' );
```

Is there a MySQL method that provides a REGEX 'OR' to be embedded within a String?
Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE record like '%cr[e|é]m[e|é]%' ;
```

Or is there another solution that would not require the construction of an excessively convoluted SQL Statement?

Comment: `[]` is for character classes, you don't need the alternate (`|`) in there, it will be treated as a literal `|` character. If you want to use alternate use a simple group with `()`, e.g. `(e|é)`. Using a class but without the alternate would work too, like `[eé]`.

Comment: No it isn't: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8334cc22a5d1e8035a8eb130619e74a

Comment: Nope. MySQL does not recognize the parenthesis symbols '( )' or the bracket symbols '[]' as regex operators. It is still searching for the literal string "(e|é)", "(eé)" "[e|é]", or "[eé]".

Comment: Have you even had a look at the fiddle? It behaves exactly as I described. (The problem might be that you mix ordinary `LIKE`, which has a reduced and different pattern matching (actually not regular expressions, just some wild cards), with `regexp_like()`, which is another beast.)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the fiddle link. Based on this bug report [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89461), the MYSQL documentation is wrong. REGEXP_LIKE() does not work. AND according to the (incorrect) documentation, even if it this function DID work, I don't see how it would solve my issue. **To restate the issue:** The user will search a database field to see if a specific String (for example, 'creme') is found. However, various records in the database field may have alternate character combinations for the String (including 'creme' or 'crème').

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone who spent time trying to figure this out.

As I commented above, REGEXP_LIKE() does not appear to be a valid MySQL function for the current release.
Here is my solution; Note that this works for MySQL 5.7.x.

`SELECT id, record FROM table WHERE record RLIKE 'jalape(n|ñ)o';`